# is it possible with html to specify table/grid organized by columns?

Tags: html, html-table, css-tables

I have a table/grid with two columns and I want to be able to add/remove rows from each column.  Currently I'm using a regular table and if I want to add a cell to the left column, I have to go through each of the rows and move the data from all the other cells in that column down in the subsequent rows.

I was wondering if there was a way either with tables or css-tables to organize by data by column and then just add/subtract rows/divs from the appropriate column grouping and not have to deal with visual rows.

Comment: add or insert ?

Comment: i think you'd better organize two tables each of them with one column

Comment: Please show what you've done so far

Comment: This question has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock - since you can also accomplish table layouts using css and divs, I think the question definitely has to do with css.  Moreover, as I looked into it more, I think if there will be a solution, it would be with css-tables.

Comment: You can create a table layout using divs and CSS, but then you don't actually have a table.

Comment: ok - but it looks like a table.. so it's a common way people refer to it.  Check the comment on the "css-tables" tag.

Comment: you can see http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero - quote "In actual fact, CSS Table has a key differentiation over HTML Table.", etc.